# How can I hardcode date into Oracle query in SSIS

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp

I am very new to Oracle database and I am trying to hardcode the date (2020-06-30 0:00:00) into the query below, however I get the following errors

[valsys_TIMESERIES_VALUE [37]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P006
ORA-01821: date format not recognized

ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from VALSYS".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P006

ORA-01821: date format not recognized
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from VALSYS".

```
"SELECT TS_ID,DATE_UTC,VALUE,CASE WHEN VALUE = 0 THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(VALUE) END VALUE_CONV ,SUBSTITUTE_VALUE
,CASE WHEN SUBSTITUTE_VALUE = 0 THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(SUBSTITUTE_VALUE) END SUBSTITUTE_VALUE_CONV ,MANUAL_VALUE, CASE WHEN MANUAL_VALUE = 0 THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(MANUAL_VALUE) END MANUAL_VALUE_CONV,FEASIBLE
,VERIFIED,APPROVED,VALID_FROM,VALID_UNTIL,LAST_EXPORT,DAY_CET,COMPUTED,MARKER,TASK_UNIT_ID FROM  \""+ @[$Project::Oracle_Valsys_Schemaname] + "\".\"VALSYS_TIMESERIES_VALUE\" 
WHERE VALID_FROM >  to_timestamp('"+  @[User::PreLET]  + "', '2020-06-30 0:00:00') "
```

Comment: You can use a timestamp or date literal, e.g. `WHERE valid_from > timestamp '2020-06-30 00:00:00'` (the hour must be two digits) or `WHERE valid_from > date '2020-06-30'`. (And if `valid_from` is not a date, but a datetime, then I'd rather expect >= instead of >, so as to not exclude midnight. What does `@[User::PreLET]` contain? The `to_timestamp` should have a date format for the second parameter., e.g. `'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss'`.

Comment: Pleas how can I vote for this? Thanks a lot man...It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `to_timestamp` is a format mask, e.g. `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'`

This is a sample usage

```
select 
  to_timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') tst
from dual;  

TST                          
-----------------------------
30.06.2020 00:00:00,000000000
```